# Apache mod_version.so not available in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

Can anyone let me know how to install mod_version.so in Apache of Ubuntu 14.04. By default it does not get installed and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this module no longer needs to be installed or enabled. At least, `<IfVersion></IfVersion>` sections work fine without any further action on my Ubuntu 14.04 systems.